# How to specify a mesh in plotting options

Tags: plotting, finite-element-method, mesh

I have a very simple question:  Imagine I have solved a PDE on a mesh and want to display the solution on the same element mesh that was passed to `NDSolve`.  I have not found an option to do that.

Could anyone please provide a simple solution or a hint.

Comment: Did you check this https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html

Comment: Did you use finite element method? In what dimensions? Why is interpolation not desired? What alternative to interpolation are you looking for in the display? You can extract the info on the mesh by calling the resulting `InterpolationFunction` with the argument `["Grid"]` or `["ValuesOnGrid"]`. Did you create the mesh before calling `NDSolve`?

Comment: This seems to be shown throughout the FEM tutorials. E.g. [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JV4h4.png) from http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html

Answer (score 8):

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[Disk[]];
ufun = 
   NDSolveValue[
     {-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 1, DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
     u, {x, y} ∈ mesh];
Plot3D[ufun[x, y], {x, y} ∈ mesh, Mesh -> All]
```

[image]

Two things to note:

1. `Plot3D` directly takes an `ElementMesh`
2. giving the option `Mesh->All` uses that specific mesh in the visualization.